# How to get Cinnamon desktop via xrdp on Ubuntu 22.04.02

Tags: ubuntu, xrdp

I have xrdp working fine with Ubuntu Gnome desktop. But I'd rather use Cinnamon. I've followed various incantations to try to get xrdp to load Cinnamon instead of Ubuntu Gnome, without success. Has something changed in 22.04?

Cinnamon works fine when I log into the machine directly, after selecting Cinnamon in the session manager window; but when I log in via xrdp, I get the old broken non-Ubuntu-patched Gnome desktop. I've tried copying all of the XDG_* environment variables that are set when running Cinnamon directly, but it doesn't seem to help.

Here's my /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh script. When I connect via xrdp, I get the unstable non-Ubuntu version of Gnome.

```
#!/bin/sh
# xrdp X session start script (c) 2015, 2017, 2021 mirabilos
# published under The MirOS Licence

#Improved Look n Feel Method
cat <<EOF > ~/.xsessionrc

export XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-cinnamon:/etc/xdg
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=X-Cinnamon
export XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/gnome:/usr/share/cinnamon2d:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop

EOF


# Rely on /etc/pam.d/xrdp-sesman using pam_env to load both
# /etc/environment and /etc/default/locale to initialise the
# locale and the user environment properly.

# (saved GNOME config)
#export GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu
#export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME 
#export XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/gnome:/usr/share/cinnamon2d:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop

if test -r /etc/profile; then
    . /etc/profile
fi

test -x /etc/X11/Xsession && exec /etc/X11/Xsession
exec /bin/sh /etc/X11/Xsession
```

When running in a local Cinnamon desktop, the following environment variables are set:

```
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-cinnamon:/etc/xdg
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=X-Cinnamon
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/gnome:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/share/cinnamon2d:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
XDG_MENU_PREFIX=gnome-
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
XDG_SEAT=seat0
XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=cinnamon
XDG_SESSION_ID=8
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
```

I've tried various permutations of that set, including adding XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP, and XDG_MENU_PREFIX, with no success. Always the non-Ubuntu Gnome desktop.